# Sorting Array / Dictionary by duplicates in Swift

Tags: arrays, swift, dictionary

I have a dictionary like:

```
[
 { 
artistName: Maroon 5,
trackName: Sugar
},
{
artistName: Lana Del Rey,
trackName: Love
},
artistName: Maroon 5,
trackName: Sugar
}
]
...
```

What I want to achieve is to sort a list by most frequently occurring trackName to the least frequently occurring trackName. In this case, Sugar by Maroon 5 has higher priority than Love by Lana Del Rey. So in the case above, the new list would be:

```
[
{ 
artistName: Maroon 5,
trackName: Sugar
},
{ 
artistName: Lana Del Rey,
trackName: Love
}
]
```

Comment: What is the format of your data? You said you have a dictionary, but wrote an array of dictionaries instead. Also your code is not valid Swift.

Answer (score 0):

Iterate through the array once and use a Dictionary to bin all of the totals by id (in your case artistName + trackName since you don't have an id).

```
var totals: [String: Int] = [:]
array.forEach { element in
   let key = element. artistName + element. trackName
   totals[key] = (totals[key] ?? 0) + 1
}
```

For your sort you look up the number from the totals dictionary and use that as your sort key.

```
array.sort { elements in
    guard let left = totals[elements.0.artistName + elements.0. trackName], 
          let right = totals[elements.1.artistName + elements.1. trackName] else {
        return false
    }
    return left < right
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use an `NSCountedSet`. Here's an example using an array of numbers but it works as-is with any array (including your array of dictionary) as long as the objects in the array properly implement the `Equatable` protocol.

```
let array = [1,2,3,4,5,2,5,3,1,1,3]
let cset = NSCountedSet(array: array)
let unique = oset.allObjects.sorted { (val1, val2) -> Bool in
    return cset.count(for: val1) > cset.count(for: val2)
}

print(unique)
```

Output:

> [3, 1, 2, 5, 4]